# Logarithm in two variables

Tags: calculus, functions, systems-of-equations

By definition, the logarithm **log** of base $b$ is given by $$\log_b(b^x)=x,$$ $$\log_b(1)=0.$$

In a similar fashion, I am trying to define a function that is always decreasing as its input is getting smaller. The problem is that my example is supposed to work with two variables.

What I want is $f_b$ such that $$f_b(\frac{n}{b^k}) > f_b(\frac{n}{b^{k+1}})$$ for every $b > 1$, $n$, and natural $k$. Also, it must hold for every allowed value that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_b(\frac{n}{b^k}) = \infty.$$ I tried defining it as $$f_b(\frac{n}{b^k})=\frac{1}{n+k},$$ but picking $k=1$, $n=b$ gives $\frac{1}{b+1}$, and $n=1$, $k=0$ gives $1$, thus $b=0$.

Could you please let me know what a well-defined function for any $b$ could be? Is it even possible?

Comment: @JonathanZ Apologies, just updated the question.

Comment: @mick $1/x$ does not grow though.

Comment: @alexravsky I could pick $b=2,n=1,k=1$ and the inequality is not satisfied.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Thanks for your attention .What about $f_b(x)=1+x$ for each $b>1$ and $x\ge 0$? This function is not decreasing, but, anyway, a decreasing function $f_b$ cannot satisfy the inequality
$f_b(\frac{n}{b^k}) > f_b(\frac{n}{b^{k+1}})$ for every $b > 1$, positive $n$, and natural $k$,
because $\frac{n}{b^k}>\frac{n}{b^{k+1}}$.

Comment: For $x$ nonnegative , $f_b(x) = 1 + x.$ It decreases as the imput is getting smaller (to zero) and the sum over k gives infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $f_b(x)=\frac{1}{1+\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}$ works.

We get $f_b(\frac{n}{b^k}) > f_b(\frac{n}{b^{k+1}})$ because we have $f_b(\frac{n}{b^k})=\frac{1}{1-\ln n+\ln(n+b^k)}$ and $f_b(\frac{n}{b^{k+1}})=\frac{1}{1-\ln n+\ln(n+b^{k+1})}$.

We also have $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_b\bigg(\frac{n}{b^k}\bigg)=\infty$$ because
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_b\bigg(\frac{n}{b^k}\bigg)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-\ln n+\ln(n+b^k)}
\\\\&\ge \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-\ln n+\ln((n+1)b^k)}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-\ln n+\ln(n+1)+k\ln b}
\\\\&\ge\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left\lceil 1-\ln n+\ln(n+1)\right\rceil+k\left\lceil\ln b\right\rceil}
\\\\&=\infty\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to specify the function should approach $0$ as its argument approaches $0$, but your example accommodates that.